Why is the divisor function not completely multiplicative?
I cannot see why that if $gcd(a,b) =1 \implies d(ab)=d(a)d(b)$ where $d$ is the multiplicative function such that if $a= a_1^{\alpha_1}a_2^{\alpha_2} \ldots a_k^{\alpha_k}$ where the $a_i$ are the irreducible (and thus prime) elements that decompose a and the $\alpha_i$ are the powers of it, then $d(a) = (1+{\alpha_1})(1+{\alpha_2}) \ldots (1 +{\alpha_k})$
Supposing that $gcd(a,b) \neq 1$ then a and b have some irreducible factor in common then $ab =a_1^{\alpha_1}a_2^{\alpha_2} \ldots a_k^{\alpha_k}b_1^{\beta_1}b_2^{\beta_2} \ldots b_s^{\beta_s}$
and some $a_i = b_j$ then $d(ab) = (1+{\alpha_1})(1+{\alpha_2}) \ldots (1 +{\alpha_k})(1+{\beta_1})(1+{\beta_2}) \ldots (1 +{\beta_s}) = d(a)d(b)$
So it seems that the hypothesis that gcd is one is irrelevant and thus divisor function is completely multiplicative, but I know it isnt true, but I am missing something (that is likely to be elementary). Can someone point out what is wrong and how could I prove that the divisor function is indeed only multiplicative?
Thanks in advance
EDIT
I see now that if some of the $a_i = b_j$ then both of these factors would dissapear and would become in the lHS of the divisor function $(1+(\alpha_i+\beta_j))$ and the RHS $d(a)d(b)$ would remain unchanged and that RHS and LHS might not be equal. Is it right?

So, try one example.  Like $d(p^2)$ for a prime $p$.  $d(p)=2$, right?  So what is $d(p^2)$?  if you agree with that counterexample, take it  though your reasoning to see which line is false. I can't actually follow your argument so you'll need to do it.  But just work it through in that one simple case.

I see $4 \neq 3$ and the mistake is that if $gcd(a,b) \neq 1$ then it might not be true that $d(ab) = (1+{\alpha_1})(1+{\alpha_2}) \ldots (1 +{\alpha_k})(1+{\beta_1})(1+{\beta_2}) \ldots (1 +{\beta_s})$

Ok, so that answers your question, right?  Feel free to post your own solution below, or to withdraw the quaestion.

You should actually say all the $\alpha_i$ and all the $\beta_j$ are positive.  Otherwise, the thing you wish were true is true for $a_i^0$ and $b_j^0$.

I see now that if some of the $a_i = b_j$ then both of these factors would dissapear and would become in the lHS of the divisor function $(1+(\alpha_i+\beta_j))$ and the RHS $d(a)d(b)$ would remain unchanged and that RHS and LHS might not be equal
